# SSIS script task variable value not being assigned

Tags: ssis, script-task

I have this script task I'm using to assign a value to a string variable to be used as a connection string for a flat file. The variable has a default path to a blank file containing only the header row, if the file exists in my incoming directory, the script should change the variable value to the path of that file. I've created a breakpoint and have stepped through this code line by line checking the value of files[0] at the line to assign the value to var, it contains the correct string value. Unfortunately, the variable doesn't have the changed value after the script exits. I do have the variables checked as read/write instead of just read. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here

    string incoming = Dts.Variables["User::DirIncoming"].Value.ToString();

    foreach (Variable var in Dts.Variables)
    {
        if (var.QualifiedName.StartsWith("User::Conn"))
        {
            string varName = var.QualifiedName.Substring(10);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(incoming, varName + "*");
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                var.Value = files[0];
            }
        }
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that it mattered that my default value for my variable was being assigned via an expression, therefore I needed to change my expression instead of my value. I changed the line in question to the below code, and all is great now. Thanks everyone for taking a look.

```
var.Expression = $"\"{files[0]}\"".Replace("\\","\\\\");
```